# SSDT: Unresolved reference to object

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssdt-2017

I have an existing SQL Server 2014 database and I want to add it to source control (SSDT in Visual Studio 2017).

I have a database project with lot's of views and stored procedures.
`MyDatabase` is current database.

Every view and stored procedure is written in the following way:

```
create view MyView 
as
    select
        Id
    from MyDatabase..MyTable
```

".." means the default schema name here (dbo). And it works in SQL Server. But SSDT considers such a construct as an error:

> View MyView has an unresolved reference to MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable.

So SSDT knows perfectly well, that database is `MyDatabase` and skipped schema name is `dbo`.

But I can't build my project with such errors. I can't also rewrite `MyDatabase..MyTable` to `MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable`.

So is there any way to solve this problem SSDT?

Comment: I would try replacing it with: `from $(DatabaseName)..MyTable` then SSDT should be able to properly match the name or skip the database and schema part at all.

Comment: I can't add reference to same database with variable

Comment: You don't have to add another reference, just use: $(DatabaseName)

Comment: when I write from $(DatabaseName)..MyTable in view, I gen error: Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: In SSMS or VS? The value of $(DatabaseName) is replaced during publish with target database name

Comment: In Visual Studio

Comment: `from [$(DatabaseName)]..MyTable` does it change anything?

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3-part name could be replaced as  `[$(DatabaseName)]..MyTable`:

```
select Id from MyDatabase..MyTable
=>
select Id from [$(DatabaseName)]..MyTable
```

> [Using local 3-part names in programmability objects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bahill/2009/08/26/using-local-3-part-names-in-programmability-objects/)
>
> While VSTS:DB does not support local 3 part names it does support the use of variables and literals to resolve references to external databases.  The $(DatabaseName) variable is an ambient variable that will have its value replaced at the time of deployment. This variable gets its value from the project properties deployment tab.  **Since $(DatabaseName) is always replaced at deployment with the target database name and references through variables are resolved you may use a variable in your local 3-part names.**
>
> Our guidance is to not use local 3-part names as it introduces an unnecessary layer of abstraction and dependency on the database name